# Deleting items from a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have the following linked list:

```
struct scoreentry_node {
    struct scoreentry_node *next;
    int score;
    char name[1];    
}
;

typedef struct scoreentry_node *score_entry;
```

I'm trying to write a function that removes all nodes that contain a certain name. Here is what I have so far but I'm not sure I'm right:

```
score_entry disqualify(score_entry a, char* name)
{
 score_entry tmp = a;
 while (tmp != NULL){
    if (strcmp(tmp->name, name) == 0)
    {
     score_entry trash = tmp; 
     tmp = tmp->next;    
     free(trash);
    }
    else { tmp = tmp->next; }
  }
return a;
}
```

It gives me heap error's .. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you sure if your code is correct?  Does it not work?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes i've tested it and it gives some error's on the heap

Comment: This code seems not to work because you don't correct the value of the `next` field from the node before the node you will delete. And you need to pass a pointer to the function not the value itself, as tmp should be a pointer because it receives the `next` field that is a pointer.

Comment: He has a `typedef` for `score_entry` which is a pointer to the `struct scoreentry_node`.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't se the typedef. it is already a pointer..

Answer (score 3):

```
score_entry disqualify(score_entry a, char* name)
{
  score_entry new_front = a, tmp;
  // delete "wrong" entries from the front
  while (new_front != NULL){
    if (strcmp(new_front->name, name) == 0)
    {
      score_entry trash = new_front; 
      new_front = new_front->next;    
      free(trash);
    }
    else
    {
      // first list entry is valid
      // delete "wrong" entries from inside the list
      tmp = new_front;
      while ( tmp->next != NULL )
      {
        if ( strcmp(tmp->next->name,name)==0 )
        {
          score_entry trash = tmp->next;
          tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
          free(trash);
        } else
        {
          tmp = tmp->next;
        }
      }
    }
 }
return new_front;
}
```

You should also obtain some book related to common data structures - you seem to be interested in the stuff, and it could be a great help for you.

Comment: Fixed some issues with the code - now it should compile and work properly.

Comment: Thnks i shall try it out. any suggestions on books related to this stuff ?

Comment: Data Structures and Algorithms by Alfred V. Aho, Jeffrey D. Ullman and John E. Hopcroft is one of the best, but I also like Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cormen, Ronald L. Rivest, Charles E. Leiserson and Clifford Stein - this one was used in our engineering school as an entry-level book.

Comment: This answer would be better if you provided some explanation instead of just answering with code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `strcmp` on a non-null-terminated string (`tmp->name`). I'm assuming it's not null-terminated as it's only of length 1. Seems like you're really comparing a character, not a string, so a simple character equality operator would be the right thing to do.

Comment: The `char[1]` member at the end is almost certainly meant to be a flexible array member. http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html

Comment: Thanks! Enlightening and disheartening at the same time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you delete a member from the list you must fix the gap this creates by linking the 'next' pointer of the previous entry to the following entry.  The code below does that. Note that I have changed `score_entry` so that the typedef no longer contains the pointer - I prefer not to disguise types.  Notice that the function returns the `head` which might have changed if we deleted the first entry in the list.

```
typedef struct scoreentry_node score_entry;

static score_entry *
disqualify(score_entry *head, const char *name)
{
    score_entry *se = head;
    score_entry *prev = head;

    while (se) {
        if (!strcmp(se->name, name)) {
            score_entry *next = se->next;

            if (head == se) {
                head = next;
            } else {
                prev->next = next;
            }
            free(se);
            se = next;

        } else {
            prev = se;
            se = se->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```